# Prevent use of unicode characters in Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a front-end developed using Angular 4 framework. Is there any way to validate a text field so that users can be prevented from using any unicode characters. Example :

½ -> U+00BD ('onehalf')

Comment: Just run regex at it `[\x20-\x7E]`

Comment: Thanks for the input! Seems like it is not accepting any characters. If I enter a regular String - ABC, it is says 'please match the requested format'. Same msg for '½'

Comment: was unable to reproduce that :/

Comment: Or let me ask it this way. What should be the regular expression in <input> tag to allow use of only alphanumeric characters. eg: "ABC CDE" -> (Valid) "ABCD ½" -> (Invalid)

Comment: @Archit Please mark my answer as the accepted answer if it's working for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a regex on the input:

```
<input type="text" name="name" pattern="[\x20-\x7E]" title="name">
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! Seems like it is not accepting any characters. If I enter a regular String - ABC, it is says 'please match the requested format'. Same msg for '½'

Comment: @Archit Seems to be working for me. Can you post your code?